# Are there any Boolean function that helps to identify the block in the sequence.

Tags: boolean-algebra

consider a bit stream $$S = 000,010,100,111,011,001,101,110,011,110,111 $$I divide these in to two bit streams(blocks) $$000,010,100,111,011 $$ $$001,101,110,011,110,111 $$ now is there any Boolean function or any other criteria that given S I should be able to identify the block one and two.

Comment: It's not clear how you divide $S$ into blocks. Is it just 5 binaries and 6 binaries?

Comment: It might be different lengths.

Comment: OK, but what's the logic behind it? Context is very important.

Comment: I need to split the stream of bits into three bits and then I need to divide them into blocks as shown, Then need to do some boolean operations on each block append back again, so when I want to retrieve data back after appending I need to know where the first block ends so that I do reverse operations on each block and append them back to get original data.